# Do axioms say "iff"? (or, is it "if", or, "only if").

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic

My guess is that they say "iff", but I wanted to make sure as math books have never made it explicit.

To take the field axioms for example, is it fair to say that it says both:

1. $F_x\rightarrow A_x$ (i.e. "If some object $x$ is a field, the it also satisfies the field axioms"), and,
2. $A_x\rightarrow F_x$ (i.e. "If some object $x$ satisfies the field axiom, then it is also a field").

Comment: What makes you think that all axioms use the same type of implication? BTW, every "if" statement has an equivalent "only if" statement. For example, "if A then B" is equivalent to "A only if B".

Comment: First of all, all types of axioms don't use the same thing, If there are two ways a thing can be dealt with, owning to different circumstances they particularly use 'if' in order to write the constraints on to the things while if something satisfies a relation only and only if some particular values or sets of values are true, the axioms use' iff' to convey this meaning. You can also check out some more details here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if .

Comment: You example is more a *definition*: "a *structure* $\mathcal F$ is a [Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) **iff** it satisfy the *field axioms*".